# Installing with source and package

Tags: package-management, apache2, mysql, source

I recently installed mysql and apache from source, and php using `apt-get`. I wanted to install php with source, so I removed php package but accidentally removed packages named "mysql-common apache2.2-common etc..."

I don't remember installing any of those packages. The only thing I did after installing ubuntu on my desktop is installing mysql, apache with source.

**My question is:** Does ubuntu recognize installed-from-source programs as packages??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. You can check in **Ubuntu Software Center** → **History** → **Installations**.